# Is there a way to find when a variable has changed value?

Tags: python

There is more to this code, but I tried to remove the bulk of the unneeded stuff. My problem is, that when y ticks over to 1, the z variable doesn't change. I'm not sure how to tie the variables togther, so as to reset the z variable when the y ticks down. I attempted to `y != 2`, however, this only works if `x > 20`.

```
x = 10
y = 2
z = 20

list = ['10']

while y != 0:

        if 10 in list:
                z = z - x


                if z <= 0:
                     y = y - 1

                else:
                     if hp <= 0:
                     over()
                     break
```

Comment: I assume the first `if` statement is incorrectly indented in the example, but not in your actual code?

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that, all the syntax is correct in the original version of the code.

Comment: What is the value of `x`? What is `over()`?  What is `hp`? Please provide a complete example that clearly shows the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: No need to be sorry - you can edit the question and correct it (and add information that may be needed to help)

Comment: What does "when enemiesleft ticks over to 1" mean exactly? Note that you need to put enough code in your question to make it a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  There are too many meaningless and undefined items in your code for this to be easy to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow,
In your case, it is working only when `x=20` because the condition `if ehp <= 0` is true when `ehp=ehp-x` is true as well.

In order to fix it and also reset the `emp` I would do something like:

```
while enemiesleft != 0:

  if 'Bow' in character:
        ehp = ehp - x
        if ehp <= 0:
            enemiesleft = enemiesleft - 1
            ehp=20 # reset it here
        else:
            if hp <= 0:
                over()
                break
```

Also, as I don't quite get what `ehp` does, you might want to decrease it differently. For example now, if `x=20` every loop `while enemiesleft != 0` your `enemiesleft` will be decreased by 1. If, say, your original `ehp=21` it will take 2 loops before reset, etc.

P.S Hopefully I understood what you were trying to do correctly. As others indicated, it was hard to be sure what you actually wanted

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the lack of clarity, it's my first time. The code is trying to simulate combat within a small game i'm working on. The `ehp` now `z` represents the health of the enemies. When this tick below 0, the `enemiesleft` now `y` variable decreases by 1. The problem is the `z` variable representing it's health doesn't change.

Comment: Well, that's what I was telling you. The main issue is in the condition you defined. `if z <= 0` will be working if and only if `z=z-x<=20`, i.e. `x>=20`. It is up to only you to choose the exact condition based on your specifications. For example, if you subtract 19, not 20 from `z`, your loop with work twice before triggering the condition

Comment: Alternatively, you could change original `z` to 21. Or , the condition to be something like `z<5` and then do something with subtraction. There are literally countless options available for you there